# Activity Not Starting From Notification

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, android-notifications

I am trying to set up my notification to lead directly to a specific activity. I followed the steps outlined in the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/navigation#DirectEntry). But clicking the notification only opens the main launcher of the app.

The activity I am trying to launch via the notification is the DetailActivity.

This is how I have set up the activity hierarchy in my manifest.xml

```
    <activity
        android:name=".SplashscreenActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".HomeActivity"
        android:parentActivityName=".SplashscreenActivity"/>
    <activity
        android:name=".DetailActivity"
        android:parentActivityName=".HomeActivity"/>
```

In my `onMessageReceived` method of the `FirebaseMessagingService` class, I have the following:

```
        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, DetailActivity.class);
        // Create the TaskStackBuilder and add the intent, which inflates the back stack
        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
        stackBuilder.addNextIntentWithParentStack(resultIntent);
        // Get the PendingIntent containing the entire back stack
        PendingIntent intent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        mNotificationManager.notify(
                NOTIFICATION_ID,
                getNotification("title", "text", intent)
        );
```

The `getNotification` method:

```
private Notification getNotification(String title, String text, PendingIntent intent) {

    return new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(text)
            .setContentIntent(intent)
            .setOngoing(true)
            .build();
}
```

I don't know if this issue is that the activity I am trying to launch is not the direct child of the launcher activity. And I am not sure how to debug this either. Hoping someone has run into this weird issue before!

Comment: A quick fix could be to redirect towards Detailed activity, from your launcher activity.

Comment: @AbdulRehman Is there a way to detect when the launcher is being launched by the notification click?

Comment: I think this would help https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/navigation#java

Comment: @AbdulRehman I already mentioned the same link in my post. I followed the steps on the google walk through already.

Comment: try some none zero request code for `getPendingIntent`

Comment: Also i see some variable issues in your code. You Intent and PendingIntent both have same variable name **intent** also, you are passing resultIntent in addNextIntentWithParentStack which seems undefined.

Comment: @RajenRaiyarela Apologies. Made a mistake while copying. I've fixed it now.

Comment: @RajenRaiyarela Non zero request code didn't seem to change anything. Plus, the documentation itself uses a 0 value.

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, DetailActivity.class);

PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent. FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
```

and use this pendingIntent in Notification.

Comment: FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP is not a part of PendingIntent class

Answer (score -1):

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Uri soundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this,"x")
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("your title")
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(soundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
```

notification code

Comment: While this may answer the question, code blocks on their own are not usually useful answers, and are more likely to attract downvotes. It's recommended to explain what the solution you're showing does, and why/how that code answers the question.

Comment: there is no need to tell the developer that how that code is work he is developer and any kind of child :P

Comment: @MuhammadWaqas Your answer will not only be read (and voted upon) by the question asker, but by others users as well. They might not understand a code block without explanations. That's why code block answers without explanation are not considered to be good answers and might get downvoted. You can edit your answer to make it better.